# when tf2::ExtrapolationException occured, move_base died

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i use Sick Tim561 with  this [sick_tim](http://wiki.ros.org/sick_tim) package ,sometime laser  will  disconnect and reconnected , but sometime  laser is OK  when navigation .why this occasionally happen, i have not found  the reason .
when laser  reconnected,the TF timestamp errors ,it throws

-
`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'tf2::ExtrapolationException' what(): Lookup would require extrapolation into the future. Requested time 806.12... but the latest data is at time 806.08... when looking up transform from frame [odom] to frame [map]`

- and  then move_base node died,the robot base  lost control.  Is there exist someway to prevent  move_base being died,  when laser reconnected?  If this exists,how can i do ?
- Any suggestions will be appreciated.Thanks.

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246362/when-tf2::extrapolationexception-occured,-move_base-died/) by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2016-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*I'm not sure if this is your issue or not as I never use sick_tim pkg.*

But I think the issue is in the transform :

> Requested time 806.12... but the
> latest data is at time 806.08... when
> looking up transform from frame [odom]
> to frame [map]

Take a look at tf and time : http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/tf%20and%20Time%20(C%2B%2B)

I suspect that you use ros::Time::now().

You should use ros::Time(0) instead to get the latest available transform in the buffer.
Because there is a travel time in between sending the transform and receiving it in the buffer.

Alternatively you can use ros::Time::now() - delay

EDIT:

See the [change log](https://github.com/uos/sick_tim/blob/2feca0dfeccc7db78d7a88173198bde4df4aef6e/CHANGELOG.rst)

> adjust time stamp - last scan point =
> now ==> first scan point = now - 271 *
> time increment - also just assume
> 0.001 s USB latency between scanner and PC for now this avoids TF
> ExtrapolationExceptions (cannot
> project into future)

You may try increasing the time difference e.g. the 271 to 350

---

Originally posted by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) with karma: 582 on 2016-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2016-10-26**:
@alienmon ,Thanks very much：) I tried to find codes which  use `ros::Time::now()`  in navigation stack,but I failed.Because  lookupTransform() throws  exception with logger level [DEBUG] ,[INFO], [WARRN] or [ ERROR],but this error without logger level .I am confused.

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-10-27**:
https://github.com/uos/sick_tim/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Time%3Anow%28%29

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2016-10-28**:
@alienmon,thank you very much .When i  try to replace the robot hardware circuit board, the problem disappeared.Even if laser reconnected successfully, move base  not died any more .